# Blazor/Razor Class Library. Dependency Injection

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I am confused on how to use a Razor Class Library that requires injected objects.
I created a new razor class library project.
There is no program.cs file and hence no  WebAssemblyHostBuilder to add services to?
How do I inject dependencies into the components?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A library is simply that.  It's not an application.  You load the DI objects in the application project.  You can write extension classes in your library as a wrapper to load all the necessary objects.  `builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()` is just such an extension.

Here's an example extension method for the Weather Forecast.

```
    public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static void AddWeatherServices(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
        }
    }
```

And use it in the application startup:

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddWeatherServices();
```

You inject the services into your components as normal.  If you use a component in an application and the necessary services aren't loaded the page on which the component is being used will throw an error.

Comment: but if WeatherForecastService is in the Blazor app how rcl know its type? wee want to use the main app services in rcl, but we have no reference to the main app in rcl

Comment: `WeatherForecastService` needs to also be in a library that both the Blazor Deployment project and the class library reference.   This is likely to be defined as an interface `IWeatherForecastService`, where different implementations are deployed for WASM and Server deployments.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your services in the razor class library and your blazor app project has a project reference to your razor class library. You add the services to the app `Program.cs` and then in the razor class library, you just inject it where you need it.

```
@code{

    [Inject]
    public MyServiceType MyService {get;set}
}
```